# Add a directive to the DOM dynamically from another directive after clicking it

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

The following code is what I have, however what keeps happening is the entire table row is completely removed from the DOM upon clicking the row.

**HTML**

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="tcround in tcyear.rounds" cw-fr-list-item="tcround">
        <td>{{tcround.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Angular Module**

```
.directive('cwFrListItem', [$compile', function($compile) {

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        element.on('click', function() {
            element.removeAttr('cw-fr-list-item');
            element.attr('cw-fr-list-item-expand', '');
            $compile(element)(scope);
        });
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            round: '=cwFrListItem'
        },
        link: link
    };
}])

.directive('cwFrListItemExpand', [function() {

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log('cwFrListItemX:', scope);
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: '/dist/tcfr-expand.html',
        link: link
    };
}]);
```

**What I'm Trying to Achieve**

Basically, it's pretty simple, when a user clicks on a row in the table I would like for details about that particular row item to appear in a new row underneath it as a table.  I'd like for this "details section" to be dynamically created and loaded with data.

**What's Wrong**

What's happening is that when I click the row, the entire element disappears from the DOM.

Can somebody help, as this seems really simple to achieve but I'm having a hard time figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Each DOM element generated by `ng-repeat` for a model collection will be enclosed by two comment nodes. The `$compile` call inside your `cr-fr-list-item` is attempting to compile the starting comment node (i.e. making the row appear as though it has been removed). The model binding for the row would also be lost. Is there any reason why you cannot use a simple hide or show (i.e. `ng-hide`, `ng-show`) or append the expanded row?

Comment: @miqid Ahh, ha, I see that now (i.e. the comment).  Using an `ng-hide` or `ng-show` is possible however, that would mean that the data was already available.  I want the data to only load after the user clicks the row. This will reduce the amount of time that the end user has to wait for the page to load.  This is why I wanted the `cw-fr-list-item-expand` to load the data in from an API dynamically (i.e. after the user clicks the row).